# How to freeze specific layers of a model inside a model?

Tags: python, keras, keras-layer

My keras model is made up of multiple models. Each "sub-model" has multiple layers. How do I call out the layers in the "sub-model" and set trainability / freeze specific layers?

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. You might get help faster if you give an example as to what you want to achieve and what you've tried so far. It might also be worth clarifying what you mean by 'sub-model' and 'set trainability'.

Answer (score 2):

I'll use an example of the VGG19 convolutional neural network in Keras, although it applies to any neural network architecture:

```
from keras.applications.vgg19 import VGG19 

model = VGG19(weights='imagenet')
```

You can visualise the layers using:

```
model.summary()
```

The summary will show the amount of trainable parameters in the network. To freeze certain layers, i.e. the last 5 layers in the network:

```
for layer in model.layers[:-5]:
    layer.trainable = False
```

Calling the summary again you'll see the amount of trainable parameters have reduced.

Comment: That's for a single model and not for nested sub-models. However, I found that the 'sub-models' are callable, so I found a solution, which to call a submodel layer as model.layers[5].layers, where the 5th layer of the model is a submodel.

Comment: Yeah was wondering about your definition of sub-models when I answered, since individual layers of deep neural nets can all be considered sub-models. But I'm glad you got it sorted